# Type error on ts.Identifier when parsing a ts file

Tags: typescript, parsing

I'm trying to parse a simple typescript file that contains a class with some methods.
i want to extract from it the names of all methods, along with some other properties like decorators, method parameters and return type.

I am struggling with the ts type definition. My code so far looks like

```
import fs from 'fs';
import ts from 'typescript';

function visit(node: ts.Node) {
  if (ts.isClassDeclaration(node) && node.name) {
    console.log('FOUND CLASS', node.name.escapedText)
    ts.forEachChild(node, visit);
  } else if (ts.isMethodDeclaration(node)) {
    const name = node.name as ts.Identifier;
    console.log('FOUND METHOD', name.escapedText)
  }
}

const filePath = '/my/absolute/path';

const file = ts.createSourceFile(
  'x.ts',
  fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'),
  ts.ScriptTarget.Latest
);

file.forEachChild(visit)
```

For some reason i am forced to manually cast to ts.Identifier the method node beacause typescript infers it as ts.PropertyName.

My code works, but I'm probably missing out on something.